# python how to put argument to function with numpy aply_along_axis

Tags: python, numpy

I want to apply function to every column in matrix. I would like to use function with arguments but I don't know how to do it, things I tried ends with an error.

code I am runnung

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4]])

def my_function(arr, arg="default"):
    print arg
    return arr

def my_function_allong_axis(M, argument):
    return np.apply_along_axis(my_function, axis=0, arr=M, arg=argument)

my_function_allong_axis(M, "something else")
```

this will produce TypeError: apply_along_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg'

Comment: In your commented code you wrote my_fucniton_along_axis, which is misspelled; maybe that causes an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
def my_function_allong_axis(M, argument):
    return np.apply_along_axis(my_function, 0, M, argument)
```

keyword arguments were the problem, because of the old numpy

Answer (score -1):

You're not passing the "arg" argument to "my_function" in the "apply_along_axis", so it will always print the default value.
I adjusted your code as so, and it works as you wanted:

```
def my_function_allong_axis(M, argument):
    return np.apply_along_axis(my_function, axis=0, arr=M, arg=argument)
```

Comment: TypeError: apply_along_axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg'

Comment: Could you post the entire code you're running? I don't get an error.
Did you change the variable name from arg to argument in the second function?
Also, which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: same code as above. I just changed arg to argument in the second function. Numpy version 1.6.2

Comment: I think the numpy version might be the problem here, I'm using 1.9.
If you take a look at the documentation of the function - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html, you can see the kwargs argument is available only in version 1.9.
Try upgrading using: sudo pip install numpy --upgrade

Comment: you are right. I fixed it as in my answer. Upgrading numpy would help too